# z/OS SDSF log auto update AND scroll down

Tags: terminal, zos, ispf

Is there a way in SDSF to mimic the direct z/OS console so that it would autorefresh **AND** **autoscroll down** to the end of the log? I figured out that you can autoupdate with `&<time>`, but it doesn't scroll down to the end of the log as it gets updated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

LOL! It was that easy. Had to use `BOT &<time>` for example: `BOT &5`.

`BOT` for scrolling to the bottom of the log and `&<time>`so that this command gets repeated in an 5 sec interval.